# Referencing Namespace from Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, asp.net-3.5

Can I declare namespaces in the web.config so that I don't have to write `using` statements for each namespace in each of my codebehind files?

Comment: Can you post samples of what you are trying to do? The question is not very clear.

Comment: I've edited the body of the question. Based on Kumar's comments further down the page this is what I believe he is asking.

Answer (score 3):

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="MyNamespace" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thanx u for reply.if i declared namespace in web.config under pages
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration> 
   <system.web> 
      <pages> 
         <namespaces> 
            <add namespace="System.Data" /> 
            <add namespace="System.Text" /> 

         </namespaces> 
      </pages> 
   </system.web> 
</configuration>

how to access in .cs file

Comment: without declaring again in .cs file

Comment: @kumar: Oh, this only works for UI code (.ascx files and whatnot) - you'll always need to import the namespaces in .cs files. Automagical importing is a messy VB feature which shouldn't exist anyways, so it's not available for C#.

Comment: @Matti, post your comment again as an answer and @kumar can accept it.

Comment: @Matti, but you don't explain that it only works for .as*x files in your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <pages>
         <namespaces>
            <add namespace="MyNamespaces.NamespaceName" />
         </namespaces>
      </pages>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

MyNamespaces.NamespaceName will be now available for all of your pages in project.

cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for namespaces or common controls:

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="The.Namespace" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" etc... />
      </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```